# Can't get Appcelerator Titanium project to read the strings.xml file for Facebook Module integration on Android

Tags: android, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am currently porting over an app to function on Android (about 70% complete) and I need to integrate Facebook login. I have all of the application IDs and proxy setup. The only thing left is the ***strings.xml*** file that Android needs under ***/platform/android/res/values/strings.xml*** however, I've tried placing this directory in the root of the project as well as under 'Resources' but it still throws an error:
`.../build/android/AndroidManifest.xml:19: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/1498915623760005')`

Inside the ***strings.xml*** file I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">Updateme</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">1498915623760005</string>
</resources>
```

In the ***tiapp.xml*** is:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application>
            <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/1498915623760005"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

My question is, where should this file be placed in relation to the Resources directory of the project? Or am I missing something completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `tiapp.xml` replace `android:value="@string/1498915623760005"/>` with `android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>`

Comment: Worked like a charm.